# Spring security custom login page witn java based config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using spring security java based config for servlet based web app (no spring mvc). The problem is how set up a custom login page because of spring generating its own login page?

These two classes do all the job needed, no any xml configurations. So how can I define custom login jsp with this set up?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyLocalDB");

        final String findUserQuery = "select username,password,enabled "
            + "from Employees " + "where username = ?";
        final String findRoles = "select username,role " + "from Roles "
            + "where username = ?";
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(ds).usersByUsernameQuery(findUserQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(findRoles);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/*.html");
    }

}

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form):

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login") 
            .permitAll();        
}
```